# How to clone docker images from local JFrog artifactory repo to a remote over https

Tags: docker, repository, artifactory

Please excuse me if the answer is obviuos, since I am a newbie in configuring JFrog Artifactory.

I have read that I can configure a replication for my local repository to a remote, to make docker images synchronized in both repositories.

The configuration of this replication seems to be quite obvious, but the problem is the remote repository is accessible only over https, I have to authorize to get access to it.

So, I am setting valid username and password at replication config, but constantly receive message "Unable to identify target URL as an Artifactory instance: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" . What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

[That's how I am trying to configure replication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH92V.png)

Comment: Are both instances Pro? 
Can you verify that the URL for the remote instance is correct? 
What are you seeing in the request.log in the target instance?

Comment: @Ariel, Yes, both instances are Pro the same version, URL is correct, I checked it in browser. Unfortunately I do not have an access to logs on target instance..

Comment: This is an important part of finding the root cause.
Can you get access to those logs? (request.log and access.log)